# HTML JS скачет страница при нажатии

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Сайт](http://htmltestcatalog.dtraduga.vh55.hosterby.com/)

При клике на элемент сердечко или звезда выкидывает наверх страницы, как можно решить эту проблему.Ссылку на сайт прикладываю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При нажатии на ссылку нужно отменить ее событие.

```
$("a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
})
```